# How to add an alpha channel very fast to a RGB image using SSE2 and c++

Tags: c++, image-processing, simd, sse, sse2

I am writing a YUV420p to RGBA color conversion algorithm in C++ using SSE2. Right now, I have YUV420p to RGB and RGB to RGBA. The results are as follows:

```
size of image: 1920 x 1200
time of RGBA to YUV conversion: 0.0029011
time of YUV to RGB conversion: 0.0044585
time of RGB to RGBA conversion (approach 1): 0.0064747
time of RGB to RGBA conversion (approach 2): 0.0066194
time of RGB to RGBA conversion (approach 3): 0.0069835
```

As you can see, the RGB to RGBA conversion takes longer than the YUV420p to RGB or RGBA to YUV420p. I'm having a lot of trouble interleaving the alpha channel in the YUV420p to RGB calculation, so I am trying a post-processing step (RGB to RGBA). Here is the code so far:

Approach 1:

```
void convertRGB24itoRGBA32i ( int width, int height, const unsigned char *RGB, unsigned char *RGBA ) {
    const size_t numPixels = (width - 1) * (height - 1);

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < numPixels; i++ ) 
    {
        __m128i sourcePixel = _mm_loadu_si128 ( (__m128i*)&RGB[i * 3] );
        //__m128i alphaChannel = _mm_setzero_si128 ( ); // Set alpha to 0 (transparent)
        __m128i alphaChannel = _mm_set1_epi32 ( 0xFF000000 );
        __m128i rgb32Pixel = _mm_or_si128 ( alphaChannel, sourcePixel );
        _mm_storeu_si128 ( (__m128i*)&RGBA[i * 4], rgb32Pixel );
    }
}
```

Approach 2:

```
void convertRGB24itoRGBA32i ( int width, int height, const RT_UByte *RGB, RT_UByte *RGBA )
{
    const size_t numPixels = (width - 1) * (height - 1);

    // Create the shuffle control mask for converting BGR to RGBA
    __m128i shuffleMask = _mm_setr_epi8 ( 2, 1, 0, 3, 5, 4, 3, 7, 8, 11, 10, 9, 13, 12, 15, 14 );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < numPixels; i++ ) {
        __m128i sourcePixel = _mm_loadu_si128 ( reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(&RGB[i * 3]) );

        __m128i rgbaPixel = _mm_shuffle_epi8 ( sourcePixel, shuffleMask );

        __m128i alphaChannel = _mm_set1_epi32 ( 0xFF000000 );

        // Merge the RGBA channels
        rgbaPixel = _mm_or_si128 ( alphaChannel, rgbaPixel );

        _mm_storeu_si128 ( reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(&RGBA[i * 4]), rgbaPixel );
    }
}
```

Approach 3:

```
inline void convertBGRi24toBGRAi32 ( const ubyte3 *bgri24, ubyte4* bgrai32, t_size size )
{
    for ( ; size != 0; --size, ++bgrai32, ++bgri24 )
    {
        bgrai32->x = bgri24->x;
        bgrai32->y = bgri24->y;
        bgrai32->z = bgri24->z;
        bgrai32->w = 0xff;
    };

}
```

Comment: Can you use SSSE3 for `pshufb`?  That's probably a lot faster; no good strategy comes to mind for just SSE2.  But if your data is originally YUV420p, you already need to do some work to turn subsampled YUV into full-depth RGB; you probably want to go straight to RGBA if that's what you eventually want.  Storing and reloading is bad for cache locality unless you work in small chunks, which could perhaps be useful with unaligned loads as part of a first shuffle step.  (Planar would of course be even easier, the alpha channel would be a separate array.)

Comment: At first I thought that this code cannot possibly be right (since it doesn't do any permutation to make space for the extra A byte) but the "trick" is that it's operating like scalar code, just using vector instructions.

Comment: Did you try just copying bytes over one by one? Let the compiler optimize the loop the way it sees fit? That way you don’t need to do any explicit computations.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I am getting 0.0069835 (secs) unfortunately.

Comment: How can just copying data be 3x as expensive as RGBA to YUV conversion? That makes no sense! Please post that code. How are you timing? Are you running an optimized build?

Comment: Why is the number of pixels `(width - 1) * (height - 1)`? Should be `width * height`!

Comment: @CrisLuengo number of pixels is what it is because I was getting a heap error when I was trying to save the output image. I will look into that again. I am posting the code I wrote in response to your suggestions shortly

Comment: @PeterCordes I think I have responded with what I'm getting above (0.0066194 secs unfortunately)

Comment: When you're using `pshufb` you can of course process 4 pixels at the time, that's the point, but your approach 2 still does that fake-scalar thing that approach 1 had to do to work around not having `pshufb`

Comment: [Fast vectorized conversion from RGB to BGRA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7194452) has an answer using `_mm_shuffle_epi8` in chunks of 4x4 pixels = 3 input vectors and 4 output vectors.  (Unaligned loads would probably be more efficient than the blending its doing, though.)  It's also reversing to BGRA, but RGBA should be just a matter of adjusting the shuffle control vector.

Comment: See also [Improve SSE (SSSE3) YUV to RGB code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4572548), and for AVX2, [How to transform 24bit rgb to 32bit using avx2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48731417)